# How to calculate a text size?

Tags: codenameone

Apparently the `com.codename1.ui.plaf.LookAndFeel.getTextAreaSize(TextArea, boolean)` doesn't return an exact text size.

I would like to determine the size of a speech bubble, or the size of a possibly multi-line text in a speech bubble.

How would I do that? Is there a utility method for that somewhere in CN1?

Answer (score 0):

This returns the preferred size. With multiline text we size based on the number of rows/columns since the text is modifiable and scrollable its content isn't fully taken into consideration for this calculation. Even when it is taken into consideration this can't be 100% accurate as even 1 pixel difference in width can cause a line break which will reflow everything. There are many special cases involved with text sizing so you shouldn't rely on accuracy. Try using `setActAsLabel` or `SpanLabel`.

Comment: Both suggested approaches `TextArea.setActAsLabel(true)`and `Spanlabel` don't calculate the correct size wen they contain more than one line - at least in the Simulator.

Comment: I think I noticed several bugs there. Here is the on regarding the Simulator: [The simulator does not render TextArea correctly #2862](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2862)

Comment: And [TextArea not sizing to content #2863](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2863)

Comment: As I explained, the concept is inherently problematic. You're asking the text area for its size but it has no clue what amount of width is available to it... What do you expect? The text area needs to have a valid parent/width before it can give you a proper height value.

Comment: It seems quite easy with Swing - first set the width to get the height. Why shouldn't that work just as well with Codename One. And you can see that it is trying to calculate the preferred size - just that it does it wrong.

Comment: This works with Codename One too, it isn't as easy with Swing as you would think. They also separate the concept of scrolling which has other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is currently no text area component in Codename One that can be used to size to its content.

Here is a custom one that does that:

```
    private class Hint extends Component {
        final String text;
        final int rowsGap = new TextArea().getRowsGap();

        private Hint(String aText) {
            text = aText;
        }

        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            int prefW = 0;
            int prefH = 0;
            Style style = getStyle();
            Font font = style.getFont();
            List<String> lines = StringUtil.tokenize(text, "\n");
            int tally = 0;
            for (String line: lines) {
                tally++;
                prefW = font.stringWidth(line);
            }
            prefH = tally * (font.getHeight() + rowsGap);
            prefW += getUnselectedStyle().getHorizontalPadding() + 5;
            prefH += style.getPaddingTop() + style.getPaddingBottom();
            if(style.getBorder() != null) {
                prefW = Math.max(style.getBorder().getMinimumWidth(), prefW);
                prefH = Math.max(style.getBorder().getMinimumHeight(), prefH);
            }
            if(getUIManager().getLookAndFeel().isBackgroundImageDetermineSize() && style.getBgImage() != null) {
                prefW = Math.max(style.getBgImage().getWidth(), prefW);
                prefH = Math.max(style.getBgImage().getHeight(), prefH);
            }
            return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            Style style = getStyle();
            int xLeft = style.getPaddingLeft(false), yTop = style.getPaddingTop();
            List<String> lines = StringUtil.tokenize(text, "\n");
            int y = yTop;
            aGraphics.setColor(0x000000);
            for (String line: lines) {
                aGraphics.drawString(line, getX() + xLeft, getY() + y);
                y += style.getFont().getHeight() + rowsGap;
            }
        }
    }
```